# Current ways to deal with node and bower libraries in Gulp?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, gulp, bower

Building my gulp file and am wondering the best current ways people are handling their libraries in node and bower with gulp. I mean, surely you guys aren't copying over and concating in full...especially if dealing with a number of framekworks, plugins, etc... on a large scale app? My largest are probably angular and bootstrap. All this in prep to copy the smallest and least amount of files over the the test and production servers. Just curious what best trends are now?

Thanks much.

Comment: I would suggest you to look at how the gulpfile generated with this yeoman generator https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular handle this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the best possible way but there is plugin in gulp which will download all your bower dependencies named **gulp-bower**
For more info you can check the documentation for the same here https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bower